# Ternary relationship in ER diagram

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

From a text description I have to draw the ER diagram of a database for blood donation department of a hospital. I struggle to illustrate one information:
"A patient receives blood from a specific blood bank".
For now I have this structure:
[image]

I though about a ternary relationship between blood, blood_bank and patient, but I don't know if it is a correct solution and how to set it.